# How can I use custom python functions in other ROS packages?

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm quite new to python programming in ROS (mainly used roscpp before). I generated a ROS package (let's call it "`useful_python_functions`") not providing any ROS node but several python functions. I wrote a python file (let's call it "`utils.py`") and saved it in `useful_python_functions/src/utils.py`.

Now I want to use the functions in other ROS packages. I added `useful_python_functions` as a dependency to the `manifest.xml` and then tried in my ROS node:

```
from useful_python_functions import utils
```

Running the node I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

As I saw [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Configuring_your_PYTHONPATH) the `src` folder of `useful_python_functions` should be part of my PYTHONPATH by default.

How can I import the functions of `utils.py` in a ROS node from a different ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11794/how-can-i-use-custom-python-functions-in-other-ros-packages?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default stating a dependency in manifest.xml adds the following path to your module:

```
<module_you_depend_on>/src/<module_you_depend_on>
```

You can check this by doing:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest("your_package")
import sys
print sys.path
```

This convention is used when creating custom messages, as their implementation will go into a folder named after the package.

Therefore, in your package useful_python_functions, create a folder named again "useful_python_functions" in the src folder. You need an **init**.py file in the folder (even if it's empty) so that python knows that folder is a root module. Then the file utils.py will be available to any package that depends on useful_python_functions.

Hope it helps, and welcome to the wonderful python language!

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-11-03**:
You're right, I forgot that! I am adding editing the answer. Thanks!

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-11-03**:
Thank you, Lorenzo. This works with a small addition: I had to add an empty **init**.py to src/useful_python_functions. (Except when I run rosbuild_genmsg() in CMakeLists.txt. Then **init**.py is generated automatically.)

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-21**:
can this solution be used on groovy? cause i have tried it, but it showed "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rospack::Exception'
what():  error parsing manifest of package state_boost at /home/chao/catkin_ws/src/state_boost/package.xml"

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2014-04-01**:
I can get this working on catkin/groovy either. I added a run depend in the package.xml and did a catkin_make and it still can find the module. edit For groovy I think you need to use a setup.py file...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For other noobs like me: I was having trouble even using a class defined in another module of the *same* package.
This is what worked;

```
[catkin_ws_path]/src/my_package/src/my_package/\__init__.py

[catkin_ws_path]/src/my_package/src/my_package/file_checker.py 

[catkin_ws_path]/src/my_package/src/my_package/script_im_trying_to_run.py
```

- _*init*_.py is empty
- file_checker.py is the module; it contains a class called ConfigReader
- script_im_trying_to_run.py uses an instance of class ConfigReader

script_im_trying_to_run.py contains

```
....
import file_checker.py
....
....
an_instance = ConfigLoader('~/config.txt')
....
```

---

Originally posted by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) with karma: 56 on 2017-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1